# How to get values of XElements from more than one Descendants in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, xelement

How do I get XElements values from more than one Descendants
See my XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

<WithoutGroup>
   <StudentId>21</StudentId>
   <StudentName>Photo</StudentName>
   <Image>dshdsdhshdsghs</Image>
<WithoutGroup>

<group>
   <groupId>471</groupId>
   <groupName>General </groupName>

     <Student>
       <StudentId>85</StudentId>
       <StudentName>Action</StudentName>
       <Image>qwerxcxcxcbvbxcx</Image>
     </Student>

     <Student>
       <StudentId>27</StudentId>
       <StudentName>Docs</StudentName>
       <Image>xcxncbxncsds</Image>
     </Student>

</group>

</root>
```

I want "STUDENT NAME" and "STUDENT ID", how do I put condition?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is code:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            List<STUDENT> list = new List<STUDENT>();

            list = (from query in doc.Descendants("WithoutGroup")
                       select new STUDENT
                       {
                           stdId = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("StudentId").Value),
                           stdName = query.Element("StudentName").Value,
                           Icon = getImage(query.Element("Image").Value),

                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: have you done **any** research ?

Comment: @Selman22 yes, I know how to get from one descendant but do not know from more than one descendant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Parsing - Read a Simple XML File and Retrieve Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604330/xml-parsing-read-a-simple-xml-file-and-retrieve-values)

Comment: @Theolodis I do not know about it??please help, I stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that `<StudentID>` always followed by `<StudentName>`, you can select all `<StudentID>` descendants and use `XElement.NextNode` to get corresponding `<StudnetName>` :

```
list = (from id in doc.Descendants("StudentId")
        select new STUDENT
                    {
                        stdId = (Int64)id,
                        stdName = (string)(XElement)id.NextNode
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: har07, thank you very much, it works, but how to show image? I am converting image from base64 to BitMap Image.