# Read from XML instead of JSON C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

**Hi,**

Today I have a code that retrieves the JSON data from a URL. It works perfectly.

But now I want to do just the same, but I want to retrieve from an XML instead of JSON.

How do I do it the best way?

Thanks in advance,

Json URL: http://api.namnapi.se/v2/names.json?limit=3

XML URL: http://api.namnapi.se/v2/names.xml?limit=3

```
    public class Data
    {
        public List<Objects> names { get; set; }
    }

    public class Objects
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("http://api.namnapi.se/v2/names.json?limit=3");

        Data result = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Data>(json);

        foreach (var item in result.names)
        {
            Label.Text += (item.firstname + " " + item.surname + "<br />");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use XmlSerializer Class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to parse your XML in C#.

For example, you can use `XmlDocument`:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string xml = client.DownloadString("http://api.namnapi.se/v2/names.xml?limit=3");

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml);

foreach (XmlElement node in document.SelectNodes("names/name"))
{
    Label.Text += String.Format("{0} {1}<br/>", 
        node.SelectSingleNode("firstname").InnerText,  
        node.SelectSingleNode("lastname"));
}
```

There are also such approaches as using `XmlSerializer` for serializing XML into your own classes, `XmlTextReader`, `Linq2Xml` etc. Pick the most suitable one.

Read more about XML parsing in C#:

[How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)
[XML Parsing - Read a Simple XML File and Retrieve Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604330/xml-parsing-read-a-simple-xml-file-and-retrieve-values)

There is a lot of information on this topic on Stackoverflow and other Internet resources.

*P.S.* In my opinion, it is better to use JSON because it can save up to gigabytes of network traffic.